# Python: Extracting Datasets in Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a weird looking dataset, where every row describes another dataset. "data" in this case is a list which I have converted to a dataframe.

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

When looking in the first entry of the dataframe above, I see a dataframe with 5 rows. This is the case for every other row. See the dataframe for the first row (row zero) here:

```
result_df[0][0]
    _embedded.results|className _embedded.results|classId   _embedded.results|uri   _embedded.results|searchHit _embedded.results|title _embedded.results|preferredLabel    _embedded.results|isTopConceptInScheme  _embedded.results|isInScheme    _embedded.results|hasSkillType  _embedded.results|hasReuseLevel _embedded.results|broaderHierarchyConcept   _embedded.results|_links    _embedded.results|broaderSkill  BC_name
   0    Skill   http://data.europa.eu/esco/model#Skill  http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/237db40b-4600...   range of project control principles project management principles   {'de': 'Prinzipien des Projektmanagements', 'n...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/concept-scheme/mem...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/concept-scheme/ski...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-type/knowledge]   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-reuse-level/...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/isced-f/0413]   {'self': {'href': 'https://ec.europa.eu/esco/a...   NaN Project Financials Control
   1    Skill   http://data.europa.eu/esco/model#Skill  http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/abb9c7f1-6d69...   Operate projection equipment manually or with ...   operate projector   {'de': 'Projektoren bedienen', 'no': 'betjene ...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/concept-scheme/mem...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/concept-scheme/ski...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-type/skill]   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-reuse-level/...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/S8.6.2]   {'self': {'href': 'https://ec.europa.eu/esco/a...   NaN Project Financials Control
   2    Skill   http://data.europa.eu/esco/model#Skill  http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/25a713ba-cbc0...   Manage the overall planning, coordination, and...   manage railway construction projects    {'de': 'Bahnbauprojekte leiten', 'no': 'admini...   NaN [http://data.europa.eu/esco/concept-scheme/ski...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-type/skill]   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-reuse-level/...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/S4.2.1]   {'self': {'href': 'https://ec.europa.eu/esco/a...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/fff5bc45-b50...   Project Financials Control
   3    Skill   http://data.europa.eu/esco/model#Skill  http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/d37bc902-f640...   prepare financial projections   prepare financial projections   {'de': 'Finanzprognosen erstellen', 'no': 'for...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/concept-scheme/mem...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/concept-scheme/ski...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-type/skill]   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-reuse-level/...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/S2.7.3]   {'self': {'href': 'https://ec.europa.eu/esco/a...   NaN Project Financials Control
   4    Skill   http://data.europa.eu/esco/model#Skill  http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/7106b5df-e017...   PRojects IN Controlled Environments, version 2  Prince2 project management  {'de': 'Prince2-Projektmanagement', 'no': 'Pri...   NaN [http://data.europa.eu/esco/concept-scheme/ski...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-type/knowledge]   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-reuse-level/...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/isced-f/0413]   {'self': {'href': 'https://ec.europa.eu/esco/a...   [http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/bec4359e-cb9...   Project Financials Control
```

Here's a screenshot snipped of the dataframe:
[image]

Is it possible to extract these dataset in every row and append it to one big dataframe? So the resulting dataframe at the end should have the size of "1716 x 5 = 8580".

I tried something like this without success:

```
column_names = ["_embedded.results|className", "_embedded.results|classId", "_embedded.results|uri","_embedded.results|searchHit", "_embedded.results|title ", "_embedded.results|preferredLabel", "_embedded.results|isTopConceptInScheme", "embedded.results|isInScheme","_embedded.results|hasSkillType","_embedded.results|hasReuseLevel","_embedded.results|broaderHierarchyConcept","_embedded.results|_links","_embedded.results|broaderSkill","BC_name"]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

for index, i in result_df.iterrows():
  for j in i:
    my_df.append(j)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use if need convert each value to dataFrame:

```
result_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in data], ignore_index=True)
```

Or if there is already list of DataFrames:

```
result_df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
```